# Idiom or proverb to point out half-measures

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

What is an idiom or proverb to point out half-measures? Something like, "You locked the door, but left the window open." Or, "You wrote the check, but forgot to mail it." Those expressions seem easy to understand, but I've heard them rarely or never. Is there a more common expression?

The question was inspired by ineffective quarantines, such as isolating somebody to their room, but letting the family dog go back and forth.

Update: To clarify, I am looking for an idiom or proverb resembling "You did A, but left out B".

Comment: ***Jog someone’s memory***? - 
it means “*to remind someone about something they have forgotten*”.

Comment: *The lights are on but nobody's home . . .*

Answer (score 1):

1. It's worth nothing that "half-measures" **is indeed** an idiom. In particular "no more half-measures" is a typical idiomatic ejaculation.
2. I'd say **"half-assed"**, which for better or worse is slightly vulgar/aggressive, expresses what you mean, maybe.  "Your plan of isolating the child was totally half-assed, dude. What about the dog?" etc. <sup>footnote</sup>

There are sundry variations like half-cocked, half-baked, etc. (I don't know "which came first", it's an interesting question.)

1. A related thing I can think of is "You can't be half pregnant!" which is kind of an inverse to the concept presented.
2. A related thing I can think of is the complex "You're a few cards short of a full deck..."

---

<sup>footnote</sup> I was going to say "half-assed" is slang, but what does that even mean any more in the English-speaking world?  (A) Maybe 1% of English-speakers can write with a pencil, they spl lk dis, and spoken speech is so bad it's really descended to being a kind of patois, an argot.  (B) With the internet, everyone knows everything at all times, so what is slang? Does it just mean "a bit vulgar", IDK.

Answer (score 1):

[A day late and a dollar short](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_day_late_and_a_dollar_short)

> Too late and too feeble to achieve the desired effect.
>   *His apology was a day late and a dollar short.*

The subject of the idiom did something, but it was inadequate. It originally referred to paying the landlord for the rent not enough money and after when the rent was due.

Answer (score 0):

The saying **[Don't] spoil the ship for a ha'porth of tar** refers to not finishing a job and risking complete failure, though further means that the job was over three-quarters done.

From [Collins CoBuild Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+not+spoil+the+ship+for+a+ha%27porth+of+tar):

> [mainly British; old-fashioned] If you spoil the ship for a ha'porth
>   of tar, you spoil a large or important piece of work completely
>   because you refuse to spend a small amount of money on one aspect of
>   it.
>
> - I think it's a modest investment that is well worth making. You don't want to spoil the ship for a ha'porth of tar.
>
> Note: 'Ship' in this expression
>    was originally 'sheep'. A 'ha'porth' is a `halfpenny's
>   worth'; a halfpenny was a British coin of very low value. Shepherds
>   used to put tar on their sheep's wounds and sores to protect them from
>   flies, and it would be foolish to risk the sheep's health in order to
>   save a small amount of money.