# What are the rules behind stock-market expressions like "I'm short X" "Steve is long Y"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Reading through The Big Short (or any other stock-market related material), you'll find such expressions as "I am short Microsoft" or "We are long this trade". What is the rule behind such expressions? Are there any other uses of similar structures outside of the stock-market context?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: Are you asking about this form of sentence construction or the meaning of these particular terms?

Comment: ***Long Position vs. Short Position: What's the Difference?*** https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/100314/whats-difference-between-long-and-short-position-market.asp

Comment: The last part of your question is probably the interesting one.

Comment: I understand the meaning behind the terms, what interests me is why it is formed the following way: Noun (He) Verb (is) Adjective (short) Noun (Company name). I understand the long/short in this construction may not be strictly adjectives, but even if they were to be considered nouns, I'm still struggling to find anything with a similar construction outside of this particular context.

Comment: It is financial jargon. *I am long Apple* is the short expression for *I have a long position on Apple*.

Comment: Hi, @user067531, yes, I understand that, what puzzles me (purely from a grammatical point) is why it's not "I am long ON Apple". Every time I come across these expressions in financial literature, my first reaction is - "hey, it seems like a preposition is missing".

Comment: *I am long/short X* is a typical expression of traders who tend to use short expressions. The missing proposition doesn't  create any misunderstanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["came up short 100 dollars" - what usage of "short" is that?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427982/came-up-short-100-dollars-what-usage-of-short-is-that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investopedia defines a *short*:

> Short selling is the sale of a security that is not owned by the seller, usually one that the seller has borrowed.

[Source](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/how-short-sellers-short-a-stock/)

### Origin of *short*

Consider the expression "[a day late and a dollar short](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/527152/3306)," in which the *dollar short* means you owe someone a dollar. This is the same sense as a *short stock*: You owe someone some stock.

(Short sale example. Typically, Investor A borrows 100 shares of Investor B's XYZ stock. They are at the same brokerage firm, and the stock is borrowed without B's knowledge.

Of course, Investor A must buy those shares back and replace them in B's account, giving rise to the maxim:

> "He who sells what isn't his'n, must buy it back or go to pris'n." -Daniel Drew [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Drew)

Investor A will initiate his transaction with the instruction "Sell short 100 shares XYZ to open." This *short sale* instruction is distinct from "Sell 100 shares XYZ" (synonymous with "Sell 100 shares XYZ *to close*," which signals that Investor A already owns (at least) 100 shares of XYZ.)

End of short sale example.)

*Short* may have started out as an adjective (in *dollar short* and *short stock*). But as parts of speech may be rather fluid, it is a short path from the adjective *short* to the verb *short*.

### Origin of *long*

It is similarly short path from adjectival antonyms *short* / *long*. By association, the financial inverses are *sell XYZ short* and *buy XYZ long*.

### The rules

If you own something (stock, real estate, futures, cattle), you are *long*.

If you owe something (stock, real estate, futures, cattle), you are *short*.

### Other contexts

The *long / short* opposites abound in stock, futures, and commodities. A *short sale* is not uncommon in real estate, although it would sound a little strange to say "Investor A is long his primary residence." Similarly, "I'm ten bucks short" is not terribly uncommon when paying for dinner or rent, but it would sound strange to say, "I'm ten bucks long."